# uninstall xampp on ubuntu using terminal command

Tags: uninstall, lamp

I want to uninstall XAMPP on Ubuntu on VM. Please advise command to archive this.

I have downloaded package using `wget` command and run `sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run`. How to delete folder using terminal located at `/opt/lampp`?

Comment: I have downloaded package using wget command and run sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run. How to delete folder using terminal located at /opt/lampp?

Answer (score 38):

As stated in [this post](https://manikandansubbu.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/installing-configuring-and-uninstalling-xampp-in-ubuntu/):

> To Uninstall Xampp, use
>
> ```
> sudo -i 
> cd /opt/lampp 
> ./uninstall
> ```

But I think you may simplify by just typing:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
```

Comment: while i am uninstall the xampp i am getting "Installer payload initialization failed. This is likely due to an incomplete or corrupt downloaded file."  Please help me on this.

Answer (score 10):

Open a terminal and remove the folder with:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/lampp
```

That's all.

But since I do not know where you have downloaded the installation file, I can not prove what was also installed.

Comment: Sure =) That was simple.

Comment: If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Answer (score 4):

Simply,

1. Open Terminal
2. Run command `sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall`

A popup of xampp will jump asking whether you are sure about this uninstallation.

Click yes

TADAA.. It's done.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type the following commands to uninstall XAMPP:

1. Change to the XAMPP directory:

   ```
   cd /opt/lampp
   ```
2. Run the unistallation script:

   ```
   sudo ./uninstall
   ```
3. Follow the prompts

Answer (score 1):

Removing Xampp completely from Ubuntu 20.04 is way too easy than before. Open the terminal by typing **Ctrl+Alt+T** and then type the following command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
```

And boom! You're good to go. If you got any other Linux distro then just go through these simple blog posts about [Removing Xampp](https://www.technocrisp.com/how-to-completely-remove-xampp-from-ubuntu/) and you'll find all commands there.